# How can I add a new item to a list of map and how to remove a item in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary

I am new in Flutter and I have the following doubt:

I have the following list of map and I want to add a new item and remove an item.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> entries = [
   {
      'name': 'John',
      'age': 21
   },
   {
      'name': 'Paul',
      'age': 18 
   }
]
```

I tried the codes below, but it didn't work:

Add: `entries['name'] = 'George'`

Remove: `entries.remove(index);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add and remove you can call the methods from the class [List](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html).
Here is an example.

```
// To add a new entry -> {name: George}
entries.add({'name': 'George'}); 
  
// To manipulate an entry -> {name: George, age: 20} 
entries[2]['age'] = 20;
  
// To remove an entry -> {name: John, age: 21}
entries.removeAt(0);
```

Comment: You are welcome. Do consider to mark this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should call

```
entries.add({'name': 'George'});
```

This will add a new Element to your list which is of the type Map.